# Signed apk crashes on upload

Tags: android, ant, thrift

Okay, so I've been struggling with this for a while and haven't managed to find anything much of use.

I have a project which uses thrift for its upload functionality.  When I run it in debug mode, everything is fine and the app (including uploads) works as intended.  However, when I make a release apk, it crashes on upload.  Everything else seems to work fine, but when I try to upload, the app just crashes.  I've tried testing unaligned apk that "ant release" makes, but it has the same problem.  I suspect it's an issue with signing thrift, but I'm not certain.

Here's the error I get when I try to upload:

```
01-23 12:21:20.459: D/dalvikvm(5299): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.company.project/lib/libprocess_rdt.so 0x40626e18
01-23 12:21:20.459: D/dalvikvm(5299): Shared lib '/data/data/com.company.project/lib/libprocess_rdt.so' already loaded in same CL 0x40626e18
01-23 12:21:20.499: D/dalvikvm(5299): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 618K, 46% free 3275K/6023K, external 3459K/4642K, paused 31ms
01-23 12:21:20.789: D/dalvikvm(5299): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 30K, 46% free 3256K/6023K, external 4735K/4796K, paused 27ms
01-23 12:21:20.899: D/dalvikvm(5299): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 40K, 47% free 3223K/6023K, external 5447K/5684K, paused 27ms
01-23 12:21:21.049: D/dalvikvm(5299): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 47% free 3229K/6023K, external 6395K/6572K, paused 41ms
01-23 12:21:21.249: E/dalvikvm(5299): Could not find class 'com.company.cloud.thrift.TestResult', referenced from method com.company.project.a.e.d
01-23 12:21:21.249: W/dalvikvm(5299): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 125 (Lcom/company/cloud/thrift/TestResult;) in Lcom/company/project/a/e;
01-23 12:21:21.249: D/dalvikvm(5299): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
01-23 12:21:21.249: D/dalvikvm(5299): VFY: dead code 0x0002-00c8 in Lcom/company/project/a/e;.d (Lcom/company/project/data/TestResult;)Lcom/company/cloud/thrift/TestResult;
01-23 12:22:33.479: W/dalvikvm(5299): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40129560)
01-23 12:22:33.489: E/AndroidRuntime(5299): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-14 exiting due to uncaught exception
01-23 12:22:33.489: E/Monkey(5299): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
01-23 12:22:33.519: V/WindowManager(208): Found focus @ 12 = Window{40aad7e0 Upload Test paused=false}
01-23 12:22:33.529: W/System.err(5299): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.company.cloud.thrift.TestService$Client
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299):     at com.company.product.a.i.run(Unknown Source)
01-23 12:22:33.529: E/AndroidRuntime(5299):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-23 12:22:33.569: W/System.err(5299): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Did you mark this Lib as a dependency in your BuildPath?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; libprocess_rdt is from my JNI, within the application.

Comment: Could not find class 'com.company.cloud.thrift.TestResult', referenced from method com.company.project.a.e.d   Its telling you it can't find this class. Where is this?

Comment: It's in a .jar file, and yes that one is included in my build path.

Comment: Is there documentation around how to use the .jar file? If so i would check that or i would be adding this as a library so you can access the source code directly.

Comment: Ok.  It's something that was made by a previous employee, so I should have access to the code.  I'll try to make it a library.  Would that account for why it works in debug mode but not when signed, though?  (I'm not clear on how it's able to work one way but not the other)

Comment: Before Signing this Application, Select Project -> Clean.